# Rendering a hierarchy of "OPTION"s in a "SELECT" tag

Tags: html, css, html-select

My problem is HTML and CSS related. I have a hierarchy type structure that I want to display inside a  list. The hierarchy contains Countries, States and Cities (it is three levels deep).

I want to display the list inside a select list, each item type (Country, State, City) must be selectable. The items should appear indented as:

```
United States
- Hawaii
-- Kauai
- Washington
-- Seattle
-- Chelan
```

The problem is with the indentation. I am trying to use either margin-left or padding-left to indent the  tags, which appear correct in FireFox but not in IE7. This is an example of the generated select list:

```
<select name="Something">
<option style="padding-left: 0">United States</option>
<option style="padding-left: 20px">Hawaii</option>
<option style="padding-left: 40px">Kauai</option>
<option style="padding-left: 20px">Washington</option>
<option style="padding-left: 40px">Seattle</option>
<option style="padding-left: 40px">Chelan</option>
</select>
```

I want to achieve consistent indentation across browsers without using CSS hacks.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select

Answer (score 25, accepted):

deceze way is much better and was my first idea. As an alternative if that doesn't work is that you can use non-breaking spaces in the tag value:

```
<select>
    <option>select me</option>
    <option>&nbsp;me indented</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;even more indentation</option>
</select>
```

It's far from pretty but it might work for you if the optgroup doesn't.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the most reliable solution indeed.

Comment: This isn't good solution, because search by letter doesn't work.

Comment: If by "search by letter" you mean typing to get the result, then I don't think that should be a terribly big motivator. That feature/functionality is very browser specific on how it works and IMO, isn't widely utilized by normal users.
If that isn't what you are referring to, then I'm afraid I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: seems that Chrome faithfully renders the &nbsp; verbatim. I had to use hyphens

Comment: `&nbsp;`'s indent in Chrome is small and is also rendered as the selected value. If this is undesirable, try `&emsp;`

Answer (score 51):

The rendering of `SELECT` elements is largely up to the browser, you have very little influence over their presentation. Some browsers obviously allow you more customization than others, IE happens to allow very little (*gasp*, who'd have thunk ;)). If you need very custom `SELECT` elements, you'll need to employ JavaScript or re-create something that behaves like a `SELECT` but is made of a bunch of `DIV`s and checkboxes or something to that extend.

Having said that, I think what you're looking for are [`OPTGROUP`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6):

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="xxx">
    <option value="xxxx">xxxx</option>
    ....
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="yyy">
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Every browser will display them differently, but they'll be displayed in a distinctive fashion in one way or another. Note though that officially in HTML4 you can't nest `OPTGROUP`s.

Comment: As a fallback you could always display them like you did in the example, indenting them using dashes --.

Comment: @deceze Quoted from the question: "each item type (Country, State, City) must be selectable". I doubt optgroup is selectable.

Comment: True that. Then he needs to either group them differently and use the group label as, well, label, or simply skip the second part of my answer.

Comment: Ummm... optgroups cannot be nested i think, I mean, I might use optgroups for country level but then I cannot use them for states.

Answer (score 14):

Just for the sake of visitors, I feel I should share this solution I devised: http://jsfiddle.net/n9qpN/

Decorate the options with the level class, then We can use jQuery to reformat the content of the `select` element.

```js
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
       $('.level_2').each(
            function(){
                $(this).text('----'+$(this).text());
            }
       );
       
       $('.level_3').each(
            function(){
                $(this).text('---------'+$(this).text());
            }
       );

     }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hierarchiacal">
<option class="level_1">United States</option>
    <option class="level_2">Hawaii</option>
        <option class="level_3">Kauai</option>
    <option class="level_2">Washington</option>
        <option class="level_3">Seattle</option>
        <option class="level_3">Chelan</option>
</select>
```

This can be extended to any level.

If you want to have empty space for indentation (instead of `-` characters), which has a cleaner look, use this JS:

```js
$(document).ready(
function(){
    var space = String.fromCharCode(8194)+String.fromCharCode(8194);
   $('.level_2').each(
        function(){
            $(this).text(space+$(this).text());
        }
   );

   $('.level_3').each(
        function(){
            $(this).text(space+space+$(this).text());
        }
   );

 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="hierarchiacal">
  <option class="level_1">United States</option>
    <option class="level_2">Hawaii</option>
        <option class="level_3">Kauai</option>
    <option class="level_2">Washington</option>
        <option class="level_3">Seattle</option>
        <option class="level_3">Chelan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the JS so that whitespace can be used for indentation instead of `----` characters? I tried `&nbsp;` but that gets inserted into the <option> value as-is, not interpreted as a non-breaking space. For example: `&nbsp;&nbsp;Hawaii`

Comment: Figured out the answer to my own question using part of @Skywalker's answer, and added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try using &#160;

```html
<select name="Something">
  <option>United States</option>
  <option>&#160;Hawaii</option>
  <option>&#160;&#160;Kauai</option>
  <option>&#160;Washington</option>
  <option>&#160;&#160;Seattle</option>
  <option>&#160;&#160;Chelan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this method of grouping creating more problems than it solves? As a user, which of those am I supposed to choose? Is there any benefit to choosing something more specific than country?

If the issue is that you only have one database field to store them in, why not have three separate select boxes (making 2 or 3 optional) and just store the most specific?:

```
<select name="country">
    <option>Choose a country</option>
    <option>United States</option>
</select>
<select name="state">
    <option>Choose a state</option>
    <option>Hawaii</option>
</select>
<select name="city">
    <option>Choose a city</option>
    <option>Kauai</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'll have to do a cascaded "onchange=populate_next_select();" for this purpose. Besides, what I want is to present the entire list in one galance.

Comment: @Salman A: Why so? You're fully-populating the one-select box anyway, so why not fully-populate all 3? However, your point about providing the entire list at once is a fair one.

Comment: >> "Why so?" The client said so :(

Comment: Hi, I'm from the year 2017. The client is still 'always right'.

Answer (score 2):

Prepending Non breaking space (&nbsp) did not work for me.

I prepended the following:

`String.fromCharCode(8194);`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this using the NO-BREAK SPACE unicode character. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Copy-paste the character from that page into code and voila:
https://jsfiddle.net/fwillerup/r9ch988h/

(`&nbsp;` didn't work for me because I was using a library for fancy select boxes that would inject them verbatim.)

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution suggested by @codingbiz above:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600605/6730120

I modified a jquery code slightly, to be more generic.
So, instead of defining each of the possible levels manually in the script, use data-level attribute to define the place in the hierarchy.
Note: it is your responsibility to put meaningful values, so the hierarchy makes sense.

Check the snippet.

```js
$('select.hierarchy').each(function() {

        $(this).children('option').each(function(){

            attr = $(this).attr('data-level');

            multiplier = 1;   // increase the value, if you want larger indents, i.e. 3
            indent = (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) ? parseInt(attr) * multiplier : 0;

            $(this).html("&nbsp;".repeat(indent) + $(this).text());
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="hierarchy" id="select" name="select">
<option value="NULL"></option>
<option value="1" data-level="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="2" data-level="1">Option 1.1</option>
<option value="3" data-level="2">Option 1.1.1</option>
<option value="4" data-level="1">Option 1.2</option>
<option value="5" data-level="0">Option 2</option>
<option value="6" data-level="1">Option 2.1</option>
<option value="7" data-level="1">Option 2.2</option>
<option value="8" data-level="2">Option 2.2.1</option>
</select>
```