# Menu tree inside dropdown/selectbox

Tags: javascript, css, select, html-select

Is there any way to include treemenu inside a dropdown/ selectbox. I have list of categories like

```
<ul id="example">
<li>Category1
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.autisticcuckoo.net">Category1 subcat1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.zeldman.com">Category1 subcat2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.meyerweb.com">Category1 subcat3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Other Sites
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.accessify.com/">Category2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.w3.org/">Category3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://validator.w3.org/">Category3 subcat1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">Category3 subcat2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT/">Category3 subcat3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i want my category listing like tree menu.  http://mackpexton.com/projects/TreeMenu/index.htm
Now am using jquery chosen to display the selectbox. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288792/how-to-indent-multiple-levels-of-select-optgroup-with-css

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that inside selectbox. You can fake it, though. Create a container with selectbox and your ul list and button that will reveal it on click. Then after clicking any item in the list you should map clicked item to particular item in selectbox and update the value of visible button that triggers the dropdown.

Comment: There is no event for reveling a selectbox dropdown so you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things. Why would anybody want to include a hierarchical menu in a select list. Select list is intended to display a list of items. How are you supposed to know which item you selected from the tree menu. (i mean how do you know the selected items path).

If you can site an example (usage), might be able to help you.

I have uploaded an image.. Is this what you are trying to achieve

[image]

This is what is called a tree menu.

[image]

The second image is from jquery chosen site. If this is what you want

you could easily achieve this.

```
<select>
        <optgroup label="fruits">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="fruits">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="fruits">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Apple</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: i want something like how jquery chosen works. It gives an alternative view of dropdown.  But i have more number of categories and subcategories to display. So it is very difficult to scroll the dropdown. Thats y am checking for an tree menu type display.

Comment: I have uploaded an image. Now this is what is called a tree menu.

Comment: Second image is what i got from jquery chosen site.

Comment: Main reason for my query is the length of my dropdown, having more number of categories and subcategories. Checking for a solution to reduce the size. So users can traverse the category easily.

Comment: Tree menu is a good choice for increasing number of nodes. But the point is where and how are you gonna render it? If it is for a form, this menu should not be used. If it is for navigation, you could use it.

Comment: For a form, use something like the 'chosen'. It is the best practice