# Angular JS subgroups in ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know how to get sub-groups in an ng-option list. I have a query that looks something like this that works fine.

```
l.symbol as l.description group by l.country for l in locations
```

but I would ideally like to do this which does not work:

```
l.symbol as l.description group by [l.region, l.country] for l in locations
```

the expected result in the dropdown that I am after would then look like this:

```
AMER
  CANADA
    MONTREAL
    TORONTO
  USA
    CHICAGO
    NEW YORK
APAC
  China
    Bejing
    Shanghai
  Japan
    Kyoto
    Tokyo
```

Is this even possible out of the box?

Comment: Check these answers : [how-to-indent-multiple-levels-of-select-optgroup-with-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288792/how-to-indent-multiple-levels-of-select-optgroup-with-css) , [nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer a solution that is built in to AngularJS. I will take a look as I might have to resort to this in the end.

Comment: I can not see in the Select2 documentation how to do this. On a side-note Select2 seems to solve every other problem I have with dropdowns... so great tip no matter what.

Comment: @DavinTryon, select2 is NOT part of the angular UI suite and requires jQuery.  There is a separate project called ui-select that IS part of the angular UI suite and does NOT require jQuery.