# Looking for HTML "select" which can handle nested groupings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a HTML "select" which can display in groups.

Chosen -- http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ can do this but only one level of grouping

I am looking of nested groupings

ex:

```
Product
   SW
     C1
     C2
   HW
   Infrastrcture
     S1
     S2
```

Comment: Why not just put nested optgroup?

Comment: Maybe combine with some css. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288792/how-to-indent-multiple-levels-of-select-optgroup-with-css

Comment: You can use a jquery plugin as a final resort ofcourse.

Comment: The solution in the link also has same issue even though with CSS. Which JQuery plugin can I look for?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 HTML prevents that. The only option you have is CSS padding and/or one of the answers mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

You can always indent the options text like below to get the desired output

```
<select>
    <option>Product</option>
    <option>&nbsp;SW</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;C1</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;C2</option>
    <option>&nbsp;HW</option>
    <option>&nbsp;Infrastrcture</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;S1</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;S2</option>
</select>
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7pfuc6rv/) how it looks like.

Comment: I would use this as my last option :)  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Here is the code of the reference site:

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="German Cars">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for more than 1 group. Optgroup supports only one level of grouping I believe

Comment: That is correct it supports one group. Anyway you can use `&nbsp;` to add the desired space, disable attribute so the option cannot be selected and some `CSS` to give a the disabled option a white background and make the text bold. Example:  `<option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>`