# Listing category and sub-categories in a HTML SELECT

Tags: php, html

I want to display categories and sub-categories in a select list (drop-down list) like the image below.

[image]

This is how I tried it in PHP:

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {        
    $cats[$parent][$id] = $name;        
}

function displayList(&$cats, $parent, $level=0) {

    if ($parent==0) {
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
            displayList($cats, $id);
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
            echo "<option>$nm</option>\n";
            if (isset($cats[$id])) {
                displayList($cats, $id, $level+1);  //increment level
            }
        }
    }  
}

echo '<select>';
    displayList($cats, 0);
echo '</select>';
```

This code display all my categories in my dropdown list. But I need to add some indent to my sub categories.

Can anybody tell how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: You shoupd use <optgroup></optgroup> for parent

Comment: @KótaPéter, I am not sure how to modify this PHP function. Can you kindly help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `"&nbsp;"` on subcategories, this is the HTML way to add as many spaces as you want

function displayList(&$cats, $parent, $level=0) {

```
if ($parent==0) {
    foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
        displayList($cats, $id);
    }
}
else {
    foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
       $space = "";
       foreach ($level){
           $space .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       }
           echo "<option>".$space."$nm</option>\n";
           if (isset($cats[$id])) {
               displayList($cats, $id, $level+1);  //increment level
           }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you tell how I modify my php function to do it? Thank you.

Comment: try with the updated answer, keep in mynd that the optgroup suggestion by @Kóta-Péter is the correct way if you have only 1 sub category

Comment: Check this great answer for using optgroup for many subcategories http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288792/how-to-indent-multiple-levels-of-select-optgroup-with-css

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use optgroup try it:

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $cats[$parent][$id] = $name;
}

function displayList(&$cats, $parent, $level = 0) {

    if ($parent == 0) {
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id => $nm) {
            displayList($cats, $id);
        }
    } 
    else {

        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id => $nm) {

            if (isset($cats[$id])) {
                echo "<optgroup label='$nm'>";
                displayList($cats, $id, $level + 1);
                echo "</optgroup>";
            } else {
                echo "<option>$nm</option>";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<select>';
displayList($cats, 0);
echo '</select>';
```