# Best modern way of creating indentation in a <select>?

Tags: html, css, parent-child

If you're only targeting Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, not IE, and you're only targeting modern browsers (released in the ~past year), what is the best way of creating multi-level indentation of options in a select without using optgroups?  That is, when you want the parent options to still be selectable, as well as the children?

```
<select>
    <option>
    <option>
        <option>
        <option>
        <option>
    <option>
        <option>
        <option>
            <option>
            <option>
            <option>
        <option>
        <option>
    <option>
    <option>
</select>
```

It would be preferable, though I don't know if it's actually possible yet, to have actual parent/child relationships between levels of options, but if it's not, at least a way of making it look like there is, where the user-experience is similar between the three browsers?

Comment: here's a similar issue already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1146789/575527

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prefix your `<option>` text with an appropriate amount of `&nbsp;` (character code 160, respectively).

Comment: Yes, that hack's been how we've had to do it since HTML2 or HTML3, same as the 2009 question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1146789/575527 mentioned above.  What I'm wondering, though, is what alternate/less-hacky ways people have found to do it, more recently, when they stop trying to support IE6/IE7/IE8/Firefox2/Netscape Navigator/etc...

Comment: I would still use the `&nbsp;`. Next to that, you can always build your own dropdown in html.

Comment: @Brian: There is none. This has never been implemented in basic HTML controls, so the vanilla dropdown still works like in 1999.

Comment: `&nbsp;`'s indent in Chrome is small and is also rendered as the selected value. If this is undesirable, try `&emsp;`

Answer (score 5):

Adding special characters certainly works, but that tends to get messy fast.

Another 'semantic' alternative would be to use `<optgroup>`.  The obvious limitation here is that you cannot nest them inside of one another, so you are limited to the simple one-level grouping.

You can somewhat overcome this limitation by being creative with your optgroup naming like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Favorite Food">
    <option value="salad">Salad</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Favorite Food &gt; Pizza Type">
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```