# How to deal with different behaviours for optgroup in different browsers?

Tags: html, css

I was expecting to be able to easily add functionality to be able to click on an `optgroup` directly in a `select`

```
<select id="MySelect" name="MySelect">
    <option value="">Select ...</option>
    <optgroup label="Group1" data-id="Group1">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2" data-id="Group2">
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="4">Value 4</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

With the supporting `jQuery`

```
$("#MySelect").on('click', 'optgroup', function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

And css:

```
#MySelect optgroup {
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1rqr6vz/5/)

**However:**

- Chrome 38 ignores the `cursor` css for `optgroup`, and ignores the event click entirely
- Firefox 32 honours the `cursor` css, and ignores the click event directly on the `optgroup`.
- IE 11 fires the click event when clicking on the `optgroup`, but the `data-id` reports the `optgroup` of the last selected 'option', which will be wrong unless the last child option is serendipitously beneath the parent `optgroup`.

In `jQuery 2.1.0`, IE and FireFox will raise the click event if one of the child options below the `optgroup` is clicked, but not Chrome.

The three browsers then also have differing opinions on whether background css colour applied to the `optgroup` should be applied to the child `selects` or not.

And not to mention the lack of support for [nested optgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)

Which then leads to the practice of [alternative hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987028/best-modern-way-of-creating-indentation-in-a-select) to `optgroup` like `&nbsp;` `option` indents in selects with different css styles for `group headers`, which loses the keyboard selection usability.

**TL;DR**
So my question is, `optgroup` has been in html since at least [4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) <del>yet seems to have been stuck in the dunce corner (Exhibit A : The link to optgroup on the [bottom of the W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup) gives a [404](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-optgroup-element)). Why is this?</del>, so is there a solution (e.g. library - modernizr, jQuery-plugin) until `optgroup` is standardized?

**Edit**

Here's a picture of the Fiddle of the CSS variances with the 4 browsers I've got on a Windows 8.1 PC - only FF shows the cursor; FF and IE apply the OptGroup's `background-color` to the options as well.

[image: CSS differences for Opgroup]

Comment: just becuase.  but really who cares why and that is probably unanswerable.  At the end of the day what one probably _really_ needs to know is how to write code that allows for these differences.  "Why browsers implement things differently" could take several books to answer.  Note that it's not the HTML that is really the issue, it's how browser manufacturers implement things in their browsers.

Comment: I would also consider posting the original question on programmers or superuser if you are looking for a more abstract analysis of why it's different.  SO is more suited to specific concise answers imho

Comment: I changed the q here from "why" to "how to deal" because there is no single answer when we are talking about multiple makers all implementing things differently.  browsers implement things differently.  see netscape/ie and all that has followed.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3414427/631619 "The HTML spec here is really broken..."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11579998/1981678

Comment: nesting is disallowed by the spec (*last paragraph in http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 and **content model** in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-optgroup-element*)

Comment: can you give a reason why you need the parent of the options to matter. What type of functionality are you shooting for?

Comment: building custom select box with group options will be a better idea

Comment: `select` with attribute `multiple` has `optgroup` clickable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to place an answer here and try to give a little perspective. The `optgroup` tag in HTML is not designed to be clicked, chosen, or used. It is meant to be a guide tool for the user to understand that a specific set of options are not the same as the previous set of options. As you are most likely aware of this, I am providing this information for purposes of guiding you into what I am offering.

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('change','#MySelect',function(){
        var test = $(this).find(':selected').parent().data('id');
        console.log(test);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

This code will register the `id` value from `data` of the `optgroup` when the user `selects` an option. This is more likely to occur than someone clicking on an `optgroup`. Think on how a user will see your data. They will look at the select and see the separated data. They may use the `optgroup` as a guide to the correct option they want, but they are less likely to try and click on it.

I imagine you want to provide some sort of informational event with these `optgroup`s and sadly I don't know how to provide that. Listening to the `change` event is probably your best chance to provide information about it and provide your popups, informational text, or what ever you can think of to get a strong point across.

Please provide any more information in the comments to help me help you. I don't understand your goal or why you want this functionality, but I want to try and help guide you in the right direction..

**CSS EDIT**

So you brought up a point about the CSS and I think I have an answer. Imagine the `optgroup` as a `div` element and the `options` as the inner items. Now in reality they are laid out that way any way so it shouldn't be hard to imagine this.

Now... When you give the css of `optgroup` say :`background: red`: the `optgroup` alone by itself should be converted, but in reality the `optgroup` is taking the height of its content the `option`s inside. Or the inner elements. In most browsers I would assume (since `optgroup` is rarely used) the `option` tag has a default background color of `transparent` which allows the `select` to have the background color of `white` or `#ffffff`. In this case the `options` would appear to take the color of the `optgroup`, but in reality they have no base. By changing the css to have a default for the options we fix this.

```
option{
    background: #fff;
}
```

In all versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome this removes the red color you see from the `optgroup`.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with the CSS in any browser I have tested (except IE and I don't really support IE a whole lot...). So not sure what to say about CSS aspect of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added an image showing the CSS differences on the fiddle provided. Which browser(s) did you demo?

Comment: Going to say that is fun... I did Chrome and Firefox, but Firefox is now having the problem when I didn't have it before so that is interesting. Going to look into that since nothing changed since I posted.. But Chrome is essentially (not exactly) the same as safari and I don't have safari downloaded here. I did IE all versions as well, but again that one proved it was happening in all versions.

Comment: @StuartLC adding an IDEA to my answer... Give me 5 minutes

Comment: hah not interested in either. This is an interesting case. `optgroup` should probably have been allowed more functionality, but in reality the `select` should be open to more free reign design. That is more opinion based and I don't have an idea how that would go, but a thought to consider for sure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to research + answer this!

Comment: Not a problem! It was an interesting thought!