# Knockout optionsText is encoded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to create an html hierarchical select based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146789/rendering-a-hierarchy-of-options-in-a-select-tag) solution and using `knockout`

However, knockout encodes the string value i return.

How can i decode the text returned from the function?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLbct/) example

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: getOptionText"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { Text: "Item 1", level: 1 },
        { Text: "Item 2", level: 2 },
        { Text: "Item 3", level: 3 },
        { Text: "Item 4", level: 4 }
    ]),
    getOptionText: function(data) {
        var value = "";
        for (var i = 1; i <= (data.level - 1) * 2; i++) {
            value += "&nbsp;";
        }
        value += data.Text;
        return value;
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace your `"&nbsp;"` with `"\xA0"` ([The hexadecimal representation](https://www.ascii-code.com/) of the Non-Breaking Space character.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the actual character for a space instead of an HTML entity. To get a non-breaking space type `Alt+255`. Just do this in place of the `&nbsp;` in your code. It will look like a normal space but will display as a non-breaking space:

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jLbct/1/

Comment: You might consider setting it to a constant variable so someone reading the code later is aware that it's not just a regular space.

Comment: For that reason I might be tempted to go with the other answer which uses `\xA0` as it also works and is more visible to other coders!

Comment: @Jameic: Yes, your solution works, but i think the one with `\xA0` is more suitable