# Inject existing input field to be select option using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an existing form field like this:

```
<input id="register-city" type="text" name="city" class="input-block " aria-describedby="register-city-desc" aria-required="true" required="" value="">
```

I want to change the field to select option without changing the HTML code.

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript by injecting the `register-city` id?

So when the user opens the page, the input field will change to option like:

```
<option>US</option>
<option>UK</option>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to create the options dynamically?

Comment: Yes I want to create options dinamically based on input from id `register-country` which is a select option.

Comment: Are you using any javascript ibraries like Angular or JQuery?

Comment: It possible to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "opt groups" if you want a single input like this -

[Rendering a hierarchy of "OPTION"s in a "SELECT" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146789/rendering-a-hierarchy-of-options-in-a-select-tag)

Or you can make a hierarchical dependency like -

```js
var cities1 = "<option>city1</option><option>city2</option>";
var cities2 = "<option>city3</option><option>city4</option>";

$('#register-city').replaceWith('<select id="register-city"></select>');
var selectCountry = $('select#register-country');
$(selectCountry).on('change', function() {
  if ($('#register-country').val() == 'US') {
    $('#register-city').html(cities1);
  } else if (selectCountry.val() == 'UK') {
    $('#register-city').html(cities2);
  } else {
    $('#register-city').html('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="register-country">
  <option></option>
  <option>US</option>
  <option>UK</option>
</select>

<input id="register-city" type="text" name="city" class="input-block " aria-describedby="register-city-desc" aria-required="true" required="" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do something like this but if you can use jquery.

```
$('#register-city').remove();
$('body').append($('<select name="city"><option value="US">US</option><option value="UK">UK</option></select>'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3h9us5u8/1/

Comment: Doesnt work using jQuery, any idea using normal javascript?

Comment: var registerCity = document.getElementById("register-city");
registerCity.parentNode.removeChild(registerCity);

Comment: it will remove the field

Comment: Sorry hit enter too soon
`var registerCity = document.getElementById("register-city");
    registerCity.parentNode.removeChild(registerCity);

    cityUsa = document.createElement("option");
    cityUsa.text = "US"
    cityUsa.value = "US"

    cityUk = document.createElement("option");
    cityUk.text = "UK"
    cityUk.value = "UK"

    select = document.createElement("select")
    select.options.add(cityUsa);
    select.options.add(cityUk);

    document. getElementsByTagName("body").appendChild(select);
`