# Tree-like Select in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-select

I'm trying to create a tree-like `<select>` using HTML and CSS.

To maintain accessibility I'd like to avoid javascript if possible.
I'd also like to avoid using `&nbsp;` instead of padding, as this prevents pressing letter keys to jump to items.

What I have so far is this:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="fluffy" style="padding-left: 10px;"></optgroup>
        <optgroup label="kitties" style="padding-left: 20px;"></optgroup>
            <option value="1" style="padding-left: 30px;">Fluffykins</option>
            <option value="2" style="padding-left: 30px;">Mr Pooky</option>
        <optgroup label="puppies" style="padding-left: 20px;"></optgroup>
            <option value="3" style="padding-left: 30px;">Doggins</option>

    <optgroup label="not fluffy" style="padding-left: 10px;"></optgroup>
        <optgroup label="snakes" style="padding-left: 20px;"></optgroup>
            <option value="4" style="padding-left: 30px;">Fingers</option>
        <optgroup label="crabs" style="padding-left: 20px;"></optgroup>
            <option value="5" style="padding-left: 30px;">Lucky (AKA Citizen Snips)</option>
</select>
```

This works fine in Firefox, but IE ignores the padding, rendering it as a flat list (quite hard to use) and Chrome doesn't render the `<optgroup>`s, which are technically not valid as  an `<optgroup>` is supposed to contain at least on `<option>`.

Unfortunately `<optgroup>`s can't be nested.

[This is how Firefox renders it](http://twitpic.com/cuaap)

Comment: All the HTML and CSS is there

Answer (score 6):

With the SELECT element it will not work. You can create a custom SELECT based on this:

css:

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .select, .select-tree {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .select .group-label {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .select .option-label {
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
    }

    .select .hidden-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }

    .select .hidden-checkbox:checked + .option-label,
    .select-tree .hidden-checkbox:checked ~ .group-children,
    .select-tree .hidden-checkbox:checked ~ .group-children * {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .select-tree .group-children {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .select-tree .option-label {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .select-list .level-0 {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .select-list .level-1 {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .select-list .level-2 {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
```

html:

select many from list (groups not selectable):

```
<ol class="select select-list select-many">
    <li>
        <input name="list1[1]" type="checkbox" id="check1" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check1" class="option-label level-0">option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="group-label level-0">group 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list1[2]" type="checkbox" id="check2" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check2" class="option-label level-1">option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="group-label level-1">group 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list1[3]" type="checkbox" id="check3" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check3" class="option-label level-2">option 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list1[4]" type="checkbox" id="check4" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check4" class="option-label level-2">option 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list1[5]" type="checkbox" id="check5" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check5" class="option-label level-0">option 5</label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

select one from list (groups not selectable):

```
<ol class="select select-list select-one">
    <li>
        <input name="list2" type="radio" id="check6" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check6" class="option-label level-0">option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="group-label level-0">group 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list2" type="radio" id="check7" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check7" class="option-label level-1">option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="group-label level-1">group 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list2" type="radio" id="check8" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check8" class="option-label level-2">option 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list2" type="radio" id="check9" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check9" class="option-label level-2">option 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="list2" type="radio" id="check10" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check10" class="option-label level-0">option 5</label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

select one from tree (groups selectable):

```
<ol class="select select-tree select-one">
    <li>
        <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check11" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check11" class="option-label">option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check12" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check12" class="option-label group-label">group 1</label>
        <ol class="group-children">
            <li>
                <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check13" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
                <label for="check13" class="option-label">option 2</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check14" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
                <label for="check14" class="option-label group-label">group 2</label>
                <ol class="group-children">
                    <li>
                        <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check15" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
                        <label for="check15" class="option-label">option 3</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check16" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
                        <label for="check16" class="option-label">option 4</label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="tree1" type="radio" id="check17" class="hidden-checkbox"/>
        <label for="check17" class="option-label">option 5</label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

IE9+ only (and you have to give the doctype for msie)... 
I think you cannot do it without "level-x" css classes, because by nested divs the padding would offset the colored background of the label too...

By IE8- you have to use javascript to colorize the labels...

Comment: I would at least use nested <UL> or <OL> tag to maintain some semantics.

Comment: I modified the example, and added a tree with selectable groups too.

Comment: You'd have to implement some javascript to maintain usability, as selects are supposed to be keyboard interactable.

Comment: Yepp, that's right. Actually you can add tabindex to the label, so the tabulator works, but somehow space or enter does not work on the label, just on the input. I guess this is a browser bug, because mouse click works on the label...

Comment: I added [a firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035790). I'm waiting for a response, and if they fix it, I'll send a bug report to the dev team of the other browsers. Tabindex does not work on labels with chrome. By msie it scrolls to the label by pressing space.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, you can't nest one `OPTGROUP` within another. But you do have to enclose them. This will achieve at least the base level of indenting you're not already seeing.

```
<optgroup label="fluffy" style="padding-left: 10px;">
  <optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;kitties" style="padding-left: 20px;">
     <option value="1" style="padding-left: 30px;">Fluffykins</option>
     <option value="2" style="padding-left: 30px;">Mr Pooky</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;puppies" style="padding-left: 20px;">
     <option value="3" style="padding-left: 30px;">Doggins</option>
  </optgroup>
</optgroup>
```

Since you can't jump to the `OPTGROUP` headings with the keyboard anyway (and only to the actual `OPTION`), there should [no problem padding the `label` out with `&nbsp;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select) to work across the cross-browser issues on padding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the option-Tags with the optgroup-Tags.

It should look like this:

```
        <optgroup label="kitties" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <option value="1" style="padding-left: 30px;">Fluffykins</option>
            <option value="2" style="padding-left: 30px;">Mr Pooky</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="puppies" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <option value="3" style="padding-left: 30px;">Doggins</option>
        </optgroup>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hm? What do you mean?
Look at W3C, then you'll see an example how you should use optgroup:
http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/select-proposal.html

Comment: What you've linked to is a proposal that never made the spec. In HTML 4.01 optgroups can't nest

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really good solution, but have you tried intending the elements with non breaking spaces (& nbsp;) ?