# padding is not working in Safari and IE in select list

Tags: html, css

Does any one know why my Safari is not taking padding in select lists? It's working fine in FF please tell me what to do. is there any issue with the doctype?

code:

```
<select style="padding-left:15px">
<option>male></option>
<option>female></option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following doctype;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Are you trying to pad your select or your options?

Comment: select 

 <select id="sexID" name="user[sex]" style="border:1px solid #C1272D; width:243px;padding-left:15px; height:25px; color:#808080">

Comment: Ironically, padding for select lists now works in Chrome for Windows (Version 30.0.1599.69 m) but not in Chrome for Mac (Version 30.0.1599.69). Any ideas why the Mac version of Webkit is not supporting this but the Windows version is?

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;` this will make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [padding is not working in ie and safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971662/padding-is-not-working-in-ie-and-safari)

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; work if applied to <select> selector, not <select><option> This worked nicely: 
input, select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-color:#fff;
border-radius: 0px; padding: 15px;
}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Even though the W3 spec doesn't disallow padding in select boxes, for whatever reason webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome) don't support it.  Instead, you can remove the `padding-left` and use `text-indent` instead, adding the same amount to your select box `width`.

From your example in your comment:

```
<select id="sexID" name="user[sex]" 
        style="border:1px solid #C1272D;
               width:258px; // 243 + 15px
               text-indent:15px;
               height:25px;
               color:#808080;">
```

Comment: HI mvChr but its not working in firefox its working fine in ie and safari

Comment: Well if you add both the text-indent and the padding-left back in then that should take care of it

Comment: sorry i didn't  get you, will you send me a sample code for it

Comment: @etoxin it's because of width with the comment `// 243 + 15px`. Remove this it will work fine.

Answer (score 15):

I know it is an old problem but maybe a newer solution help people working on it now.

I added `-webkit-appearance: initial;` to my style with padding to fix the problem.

`-webkit-appearance: none;` didn't help in my case because it shows the select as a textbox instead.

Tested on...

> Safari v5.1.7 (7534.57.2) on windows
>
> Safari v8.0.6 (10600.6.3) on Mac
>
> iPhone 6

Comment: This just saved me, thank you.  I tried using text-indent but the indentation size was different in every browser.  I set it back to using left padding and added -webkit-appearance: initial; and it worked great!

Comment: Beast! Worked well.

Answer (score 12):

Use a combination of text-indent and line-height to create the illusion of padding. Works in Safari and Should work in IE as well.

```
<select style="text-indent:15px; line-height:28px;">
 <option>male</option>
 <option>female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @anglimass I wouldn't expect a front-end developer to be using IE7! :) Sites like jsFiddle are targetted more toward users with modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have just been researching the same problem. The answer I have come up with is to set the border properties to be the padding, but transparent. For example

Original:

```
select.paddedBox {
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Becomes:

```
select.paddedBox {
    border-bottom:solid 0px transparent;
    border-left:solid 15px transparent;
    border-right:solid 0px transparent;
    border-top:solid 0px transparent;
}
```

If you still want to use a border, then you can use the outline property to set it

Answer (score 1):

Try this this works for firefox,ie some truble with padding but works with background image.
Best works in google chrome and firefox.
This do not work in opera at all but padding works.
So i do not care it doesn't work in opera or other browser because i hate them and it is not porssible to fix all problems to work great in all browsers.

Just make select option 208 px image and put it  like this.
It has some hack elements for ie ;)

```
.sl{
background-color: Transparent;

border: 0;
background: #181818;
color: #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding: 15px;
padding-left: 5px; 
font-size: 8pt;
line-height: 10px;

width: 208px;
height: 29px;
-webkit-appearance: none;

}



<select style="background: url(select.gif) no-repeat 0 0;" name="some_countries" class="sl">
<option style="background: #000;"  value="">What you need ?</option>
<option style="background: #000;" value="">I think it's good</option>
<option style="background: #000;"  value="">what do you think ?</option>
<option style="background: #000;" value="">Do you think the same lime me ? :)</option>
<option style="background: #000;"  value="">So what are you wating ?</option>
<option style="background: #000;" value="">Grab it now and be happy ;)</option>
</select>
```

See in the action how it looks like ;)

I hope you helped some ;)

Answer (score 1):

For particular select box apply CSS as "-webkit-appearance:none;"

Answer (score 1):

For me worked

```
-webkit-appearance : caret;
```

"none" - removed caret in chrome/firefox

"initial" - made my selectboxes jumping when hovering over them in chrome

Comment: best solution: using text-indent (as suggested in other answers) adds a DIFFERENT amount of space in different browsers. and -webkit-appearance: none or initial removes the caret

Answer (score 0):

For me worked adding the padding manually with `text-indent` and `height`:

```
.your-select {
   text-indent: 15px;  // padding left
   height: 15px        // padding top and bottom
}
```