# padding is not working in ie and safari

Tags: html, css

I used a padding-left in selet list

```
<select style="padding-left:15px">
<option>male></option>
<option>female></option>
</select>
```

its working fine in FF but not in safari and ie

Then 
 I have tried a text-indent in it

```
<select style="width:258px;text-indent:15px;">
<option>male></option>
<option>female></option>
</select>
```

Now its working fine in Safari and ie but its not working in FF,
Please tell me is there any method which i can used to work it properly in all browser

Thanks

Comment: This question is better for doctype.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box

Answer (score 0):

Might not seem the best solution, but put **`&nbsp;`** as much as you want before the option values.

```
<select>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp; male></option>
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp; female></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's anybody out there who's still scratching their head over this, I hope this will help. I faced these problems recently and playing around with safari i found that safari does not like ***"padding-left:15px;"*** or anything else with a ***"-left or -right"*** for that matter. Also, found that replacing the ***"padding-left:15px;"*** with ***"padding:0 0 0 15px"*** seems to work.

This seems to a problem with older versions of mozilla too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work in IOS 6

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried it on iOS6. Will comment here if I find anything