# Add padding/margin to ng-options - Angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this code :

```
<select style="font-size:0.9em;" ng-model="course" ng-options="c.Id as c.Name for c in model.courses">
<option value="">--select--</option>
```

I need to add padding/margin for each of the options.

Is there a straight way of doing this ?

Comment: There is no way to adding padding/margin to the options. Alternatively could use a custom dropdown which can be created easily using [angular-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: hope this link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23906973/3940478

Comment: @UnknownUser Thanks. Using angular-bootstrap dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because the select list is rendered by browser/os.

But you can use some third party plugin like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) ([angularjs directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2))