# html Dropdown Option padding is not working in IE & Chrome

Tags: html

I want to add padding/margin for Options. I've tried with below style. It is not adding any space in IE & Chrome but working as expected in Firefox

```
#DDLID option {
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very helpful. What actually happens? Does it do something different in browsers other than IE and Chrome?

Comment: Can you post the CSS and HTML? Maybe post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Styling to select option is limited with basic HTML & CSS. You try to use a js framework like jquery or dojo.

See this page for similar question
[Adding padding to select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186777/adding-padding-to-select-options)