# Css - Select with a background image and padding of selection (IE)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a problem with select input to be properly displayed on Internet Explorer, though it works well on Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Selection text goes all the way down to the left and should have 60px of left padding as on chrome, safari and firefox.

Please test it on the jsfiddle that I prepared. Could you help please?

HTML

```
<div id="form-selector">    
<select name='someinput' id='someinput' class="form-control img-input">
<option value="" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#form-selector select {
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000000;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}

// Firefox Fix
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#form-selector select {
   text-indent: 30px;
} }


.img-input { 
background:url(http://placehold.it/60x30) no-repeat left center #ffffff !important;
  padding-left:60px; }
```

JS FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/15/

Answer (score 1):

@Nita I had no issues with
・Safari
・Chrome
・Opera
・IE 10

but I had issues with Firefox

try adding this to your code

```
#form-selector select {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

and by the way you can download safari for windows

**EDIT**
solution for Safari can be seen here
[Padding doesn't work on select tags in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615071/padding-doesnt-work-on-select-tags-in-safari)

Comment: from what I manage to find out Safari for windows is discontinued. I belive you had no problem on safari beacouse -webkit-appearance: in jsfiddle was set to: "none" instead of: "menulist"; . So if is set to none select navigation doesnt show. Can you check out updated jsfiddle pls

Comment: i made another version with padding-left: 60px; in #form-selector -  https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/3/

Comment: @Nita I tried it on Safari 5.1.7 drop down shows, how did you find out your screen does not show?

Comment: @Nita try the line-height and text-indent hack
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615071/padding-doesnt-work-on-select-tags-in-safari

Comment: how did i find out ....? i tried a lot of diffirent options yesterday while being on the skype with someone else. i will try your sugesstion ..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/6/ could you check if this is showing well, I updated it with text-indent

Comment: @Nita yep Good with Safari.

Comment: Thank you @ha_ryu. I gonna double check it later on actual form (I will let you know if is all ok), could you update you answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/02uj91gp/15/ - good with Safari, Firefox and Chrome > There is still a problem with IE

Comment: @Nita which version of IE? and I cannot comment much on this thread, I think there's a limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135251/discussion-between-nita-and-ha-ryu).