# Select Padding in IE8

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css for select:

```
select{
    border: 1px solid #707A68;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 0px 0 5px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

The border radius does not work in IE and I am Ok with that but the padding is also not rendering. Is there any workaround or am i doing anything wrong? works fine in Chrome and FF

this is the entire code on the page:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello World" />
<select>
<option> Option one</option>
    <option> Option two</option>
</select>

<style>
select{
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px;
display:block;
padding:20px;

}
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [padding is not working in Safari and IE in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966855/padding-is-not-working-in-safari-and-ie-in-select-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer! I just had to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to my code !

Comment: One of those "Doh!" moments. -Homer

Comment: Does IE9 support padding in negative values.I am trying to customize the select option in IE9,sample in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qhCsJ/2187/ is working if i implement it in my project it is not working.Width of select is not rendering in IE9,so i tried with padding-right:-10px which is also not working.See my so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384907/drop-down-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie9. If possible please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using?, because I tested it in IE8 and I get the padding.

[image]

You can try `-ms-border-radius: 4px;` to get the border-radius, at least with IE 9 and IE10 it should work.

Comment: I am using the same version and I see the the `select` as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

`<select>`'s are inline elements and if you want padding to be applied to inline elements you need to add display:block; which will make it a block element. Tested on IE8.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs3E8/4/

Comment: No, not because `select` is inline. Because `select` is a replaced element! Normal inline elements do get padding. By the way, you have a typo in your fiddle.

Comment: @mcmwhfy Iopened the fiddle link in IE 8 and it was working. but when i wrote the same code in a file and ran it it was not. any idea why?
http://screencast.com/t/sjtWsSgs

Comment: I must see html and css code from that page in order to give you an answer, maybe because has a constraint from other element.

Comment: @mcmwhfy i have made an edit to my question to show the entire code on the page. there is nothing else on the page. I made it to test it.

Answer (score 0):

use this css for all browser  +

```
<select>
<option> Option one</option>
    <option> Option two</option
</select>

select{
margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
        display:block;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px 5px #000;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;

}
```