# IE only padded <select> drop down issue

Tags: html, css

I have a select list with some padding to the left:

```
<select>
    <option>Opt A</option>
    <option>Opt B</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select
{
padding-left:20px;
}​
```

In every browser besides IE (I'm using IE8, Win XP, IE8 Standards), I can easily open the select by clicking on the padding to the left of the dropdown. However, in IE it takes two clicks to open up the drop down using this padding.

How can I open up the drop down menu in IE by clicking on this padded area using a single click? I'm willing to use js if I absolutely have to but would like to avoid it.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTpnf/1/) for an example of the issue. Click the padded area on the left to see the functionality in IE.

**EDIT:**

I should clarify. I already have a styled dropdown which is a combination of css and regular HTML. The drop down has an arrow image on the left which is why the padding on the text is important. I don't want to change any of this. I only want it to function correctly in IE when the padded area is clicked.

**WORKAROUND**

As a workaround, I have removed the padding from the CSS and now I am padding the actual text in the options with `nbsp;` to simulate padding. Very much a hack as it now stops any users from typing into the select box to jump to specific values. But since I need to support IE, this may have to be the way that I go for now.

```
 <select>
   <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Opt A</option>
   <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Opt B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at this: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?593031-Padding-on-select-element
In short, padding on select tags is known to be a bit buggy in IE.

Comment: You might try using `text-indent` and `line-height`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966855/padding-is-not-working-in-safari-and-ie-in-select-list

Comment: `text-indent` doesn't seem to do anything in ie8 drop downs. The padding gets stripped away. It works in other browsers but doesn't help the ie issue. http://jsfiddle.net/YTpnf/3/

Comment: Have you tried adding `float: left;` to your `select` style?

Comment: Yup. Doesn't change the strange functionality. :http://jsfiddle.net/YTpnf/13/

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in IE, some properties are broken with `<select>`, now, since you're open to new and different solutions, I would recommend these jquery solutions:

- [Option 1](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)
- [Option 2](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplebasic.aspx)
- [Option 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html) (this one is not jquery)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have used chosen in the past but this isn't what I'm looking for in this case. I just want to make my existing drop down implementation work in IE.