# How to apply CSS to a Mac Chrome Select Box?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, padding

Doesn't matter what I do, using Mac OSX 10.9.2 and Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152, `padding`, `background-color`, nothing works.  I am really just wanting to apply a `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` of `5px` on a `select` element, works everywhere cept Chrome on a MAC OSX.  What gives?  How to do this globally on all platforms??

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to apply `-webkit-appearance:none;` when adding CSS to select elements in webkit browsers.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/XxkSC/3830/

Comment: Wow, does this apply to any other browsers also?  Or just Chrome?  I mean, do other browsers have a prefix for this also?

Comment: Ok, but I want the arrow in the select box, but just want padding added.  `-webkit-appearance: none` removes the arrow for the select box, but how to get it back?

Comment: You could use a background image TUTORIAL http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do!

Comment: Better answer is in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966855/padding-is-not-working-in-safari-and-ie-in-select-list/2967371#2967371

Answer (score 9):

There is better option to achieve a natural design:

```
height:30px;
background:#ffffff;
```

[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jywza6f6/)

p.s

Vector's answer is hiding the arrows on the right side.

Comment: Oh wow, so padding doesn't work, but height and border do?! Seems very arbitrary..

Answer (score 3):

Add the following property to your select in your css file:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

Comment: Ok, but I want the arrow in the select box, but just want padding added.  `-webkit-appearance: none` removes the arrow for the select box, but how to get it back?

Comment: @Almog_0 answer fix the arrow problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **bootstrap**, you can add class `custom-select`:

```
<select class="form-control custom-select">
```

After adding it, you can eventually adjust height by adding `line-height` property to css:

```
select {
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#custom-select

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not only for `select` but also for `input` and `textarea`.

```
select,
textarea,
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
       -moz-appearance: none !important;
            appearance: none !important;
}
```

I also applied the solution for all browsers, so it should work the same way everywhere.

`!important` did the trick for me, but it will depend if you will need it or not.