# I have a search button that contains options and each option will show data to associated query, I want to make some sub-options for certain options

Tags: javascript, php, html, list, backend

I have a search button that contains options and each option will show data according to its corresponding query, the thing is i want to make some sub-options for certain options that looks like when you right click the desktop windows it shows a list and some elements contain more elements inside them

this is what i'm working on:
[image: this is what i'm working on]

this is what i want to do:
[image: this is what i want to do]

and this is my code

```
    <?php
// Assuming you have a database connection
// Replace these values with your actual database credentials
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stage";

// Create a connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check the connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$output = "";
// Handle form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $search1 = $_POST["search1"];
    $search2 = $_POST["search2"];

    // Perform different queries based on the selected options
    if ($search1 === 'finance') {
        if ($search2 === 'Clients') {
            $queryName = "Total Clients";
            $query = "SELECT count(id_client) as Total_Clients FROM `client`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'Total_Devis') {
            $queryName = "Total Devis";
            $query = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(totale_devis) , 3) as Total_Devis FROM `devis_client`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'societe') {
            $queryName = "Total Societes";
            $query = "SELECT count(id_societe) as Total_Societés from societe;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'fournisseurs') {
            $queryName = "Total Fournisseurs";
            $query = "SELECT count(id_fournisseur) as Total_Fournisseurs FROM `fournisseur`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'produit') {
            $queryName = "Total Produit";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_produit) as Nom FROM produit;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        }
    } elseif ($search1 === 'crm') {
        if ($search2 === 'leads') {
            $queryName = "Total Leads";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_task) as Total_Leads FROM `lead`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'opportunites') {
            $queryName = "Total Opportunites";
            $query = "SELECT count(id) as Total_Opportunités FROM `opportunite`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'cases') {
            $queryName = "Total Cases";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_case) as Total_Cases FROM `cases`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'contacts') {
            $queryName = "Total Contacts";
            $query = "SELECT count(id_contact) as Total_Contacts FROM `contact`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        } elseif ($search2 === 'contrats') {
            $queryName = "Total Contrats";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_contrat) as Total_Contrats FROM `contrat_client`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        }
        
    } elseif ($search1 === 'projets') {
        if ($search2 === 'projets') {
            $queryName = "Total Projets";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(id_project) as Total_Projets FROM `projects`;";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $output = displaycount($queryName, $result);
        }
    }
}

// Function to display the query result
function displaycount($queryName, $result) {
    $output = "";
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        
            $output .= "<ul>"; // Start an unordered list for multiple rows

            // Get column names from the result set metadata
            $columns = $result->fetch_fields();
            $columnNames = array_map(function ($column) {
                return $column->name;
            }, $columns);
            
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // Display values for each column dynamically
                $output .= "<li>";
                foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
                    $output .= "$columnName: " . $row[$columnName] . " | ";
                }
                $output = rtrim($output, ' | '); // Remove the trailing comma and space
                $output .= "</li>";
            }
            $output .= "</ul>"; // Close the unordered list
        
    }else {
        $output .= "<strong>No results found.</strong></p>";
    }
    return $output;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .dropdown-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  select {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Formulaire</h2>

  <form method="post" action="">
    <label for="search1">Search 1:</label>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <select id="search1" name="search1" onchange="updateSearch2Options()">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choisissez une option</option>
                <option value="finance">Finance</option>
                <option value="crm">CRM</option>
                <option value="projets">Projet</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </div>

    <label for="search2">Search 2:</label>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <select id="search2" name="search2">

            </select>
        </li>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
  <?php echo $output; ?>

<script>
var optionsMapping = {
  'finance': {
    'Clients': {
        'Sub-Options': ['annee', 'devis', 'total'],
        },
        'Total_Devis': [],
        'societe': [],
        'fournisseurs': [],
        'produit': [],
    },
    'crm': {
        'leads': [],
        'opportunites': [],
        'cases': [],
        'contacts': [],
        'contrats': [],
    },
    'projets': {
        'projets': [],
    },
};


function updateSearch2Options() {
    var search1Value = document.getElementById('search1').value;
    var search2Select = document.getElementById('search2');

    // Clear existing options
    search2Select.innerHTML = '';

    // Get options for the selected value in search1
    var options = optionsMapping[search1Value];

    // Add new options based on the selected value in search1
    addOptions(search2Select, Object.keys(options));

    // Check if there are sub-options and update the second dropdown accordingly
    var selectedSearch2Value = search2Select.value;
    if (options[selectedSearch2Value] && Array.isArray(options[selectedSearch2Value])) {
        addOptions(search2Select, options[selectedSearch2Value]);
  }
}

        function addOptions(selectElement, optionsArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
                addOption(selectElement, optionsArray[i]);
            }
        }

        function addOption(selectElement, optionValue) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = optionValue;
            option.text = optionValue;
            selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

        // Initial call to populate the second dropdown
        updateSearch2Options();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488968/html-css-nested-options-in-a-select-field).

Comment: Ok. So, explain what you've tried, where you're (presumably) getting stuck exactly, and what programming question you would like to ask the community. "I want" isn't a question, and doesn't describe any kind of problem in the code you've shown us. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. As you're new (welcome) please also take the [tour] (your empty profile tells me you didn't do so when the system suggested it to you before posting anything). You can [edit] your question to make it clearer. Thanks.