# Can I make it so that some rows in a select cannot be clicked?

Tags: html, css

I have a standard type of select list:

```
<select>
  <option value="cars1">Cars 1</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="cars2">Cars 2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This is just an example but what I would like to do is to make Cars 1 and Cars 2 in the list as headings that cannot be selected.

Is there some way that I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's called an `<optgroup>`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2ACv/1/)

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Cars 1">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cars 2">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: @pimvdb - Not part of the original question but do you know if it is possible to have different levels of optgroup?

Comment: @Gemma: Looks like it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `disabled` attribute:

```
<select>
  <option value="cars1" disabled>Cars 1</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="cars2" disabled>Cars 2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/bAum7qiP)**

Answer (score 2):

Use `optgroup` [tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup)

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Cars 1">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cars 2">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: because its the same as the other answer, with not any difference

Comment: @GeoPhoenix - Sometimes we all type the same thing, and post within seconds of each other, so on questions that have an obvious answer you'll see a bunch of similar answers given within a short timeframe, no need to downvote just for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are looking for optgroup:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Cars 1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Cars 2">
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </optgroup>
</select> ​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wjYRd/)