# Adding items to nested lists of categories

Tags: php, nested-lists

Currently, for adding category into another category, I am displaying a dropdown menu

that looks like this

```
root
- Level-1
-- Level-2
--- Level-3
-- Another Level-2
- Level-1 again
```

And so on, which looks ugly & it is a bad user experience since there are many categories & sub-categories & sub-sub-categories ...etc.

so basically, I am looking for suggestions on improving the user experience, How to make it clear which category belongs to which?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information on the optgroup tag.  I'm not sure if it supports multiple levels of nesting yet, but it may help with at least the first level: [Nesting optgroups in a dropdownlist/select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)

Comment: The `<optgroup>` element only works with `<select>`s which are used in `<form>`s. That is probably not optimal for navigation menus.

Comment: He said it was a category drop down list.  Where does he say its for navigation?

Comment: This would mean I'll either have to add the opt-group with an option which will display the same word twice or just make the main group not clickable which does not work well. Plus it doesn't seem to support more than one level.