# print multilevel child parent categories into optgroup and selectbox

Tags: php, mysql

i have this category MySql table:

```
id , name , parent
```

Now with this `function` i list categories in `selectbox` and `optgroup` `html` tags:

```
$options    = array();
$categories = DataAccess::fetch("
  SELECT 
    * , p.name AS parent 
  FROM 
    cats AS child
  INNER JOIN
    cats AS p ON p.id = child.parent
");
foreach($categories as $category){
  $parent = $category['parent'];
  if (! isset($options[$parent])) $options[$parent] = array();
  $options[$parent][$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}
echo '<select>';
$selid = 13;
foreach($options as $group => $option) {
  printf('<optgroup label="%s">', $group);
  foreach ($option as $id => $label) {
   $selcat = ($selid == $id) ? 'selected' : '';
    printf('<option %s value="%s">%s</option>',$selcat, $id, $label);

  }
  printf('</optgroup>');
}
echo "</select>";
```

This function ouhput worked for `One child` parent categories and output is:

```
<select class="selectpicker" >
   <optgroup label="News">
     <option selected value="13">War</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="article">
     <option selected value="14">tech</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Now, I have Three problem:**

1- if i create many child This function notwork and print only `One Child`. i need to Like This:

```
News
--Sport
--War
--tech
Article
--tech
--php
--linux
```

2 - in need to print `Multilevel` categories with `optgroup` Like This:

```
News
--Sport
----Sky
----Football
------Football-1
--War
----War1
--tech
Article
--tech
----tech2
------tech3
--php
--linux
```

3 - Not Print categories if parent = 0 (root), This print only categories with child parent.

**how do fix/print this?**

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `select` and `optgroup` don't support multiple levels [although standard says they should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select). You'll have to manually left pad your options with `&nbsp;` according to their level. Normal spaces don't work.

You don't seem to have implemented this multilevel tree yet. I'd start by reading the answers on this [question](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Then I'd write a simple recursive function like this:

```
function walkTree($nodes, $level = 0) {
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        echo '<option>' . str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level) . $node->label . '</option>';
        if($node->children) {
            walkTree($node->children, $level + 1); 
        }
    }
}

walkTree($root->children);
```

This assumes you have an object hierarchy, but it's not necessary. You can use your existing database and write a function that returns all child nodes of another node:

```
function getChildren($id) {
    $categories = DataAccess::fetch("
      SELECT 
        *
      FROM 
        cats
      WHERE 
        cats.parent = $id
    ");

    return $categories;
}
```

Then you'd need to get the initial list of root nodes (`WHERE cats.parent IS NULL` maybe?)
and pass it to `walkTree`, where `$node->children` is replaced by `getChildren($node->id)`.

Obviously this means a lot of querying. You either need to switch to a nested set hierarchy or something similar, or maybe cache the resulting HTML.