# Angular Material nested optgroups

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select) I found that it isn't possible to have nested `optgroups` as it's not part of the HTML5 spec.
It is possible to apply styles yourself, but I would rather avoid that if it's possible in angular material.

"Under the hood" angular material swaps a lot of elements for divs and applies custom styling. Which makes me think they might handle this situation.

If I have the following code, I would expect the `md-optgroup` with `label="Second level deep"` to be indented further.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mdyjOfbsOhAkCBLKqVSv?p=preview)

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.someModel">
        <md-optgroup label="One level deep">
            <md-option>
                One level deep
            </md-option>
        </md-optgroup>
        <md-optgroup label="Another group">
            <md-optgroup label="Second level deep">
                <md-option>Two levels deep</md-option>
            </md-optgroup>
        </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

However, all `md-optgroups` are not indented and displayed the same.

This is how it currently looks:

[image: How it actually looks]

I can't see anything in the [demos](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) or [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) about this (in fact they they don't have any docs for `md-optgroup` at all), but the docs can sometimes be out of date/incomplete.

Is it possible to have nested option groups with different indentation?

If not, what is the best way to achieve this using what is available in angular material? Should I use [flex](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) etc.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: How I want it to look]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of time to think about it, I managed to do it using `flex-offset`.

You can simply apply `flex-offset` to the `md-optgroup`.

I used `flex-offset="5"` because that looked the most sensible but any offset will work.

I added additional nesting and options to clarify the point a bit better.

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cw90urvr3TkodtOP2Ru8?p=preview)

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.someModel">
      <md-optgroup label="One level deep">
          <md-option>
              One level deep
          </md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
      <md-optgroup label="Another group">
          <md-optgroup flex-offset="5" label="Second level deep">

              <md-optgroup flex-offset="5" label="3 deep now and we want to see what happens with long text">
                <md-option>Some more options</md-option>
              </md-optgroup>

              <md-option>Two levels deep</md-option>
              <md-option>Two levels deep again</md-option>

          </md-optgroup>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

Comment: how show check box icon in this scenario.(md-cion with google fonts not working for this case)