# Angularjs conditional elements in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an an array of objects in javascript:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "Item 1", subItems: []},
    {id: 2, name: "Item 2", subItems: []},
    {id: 3, name: "Item 3", subItems: [[
        {id: 4, name: "Item 3.1"},
        {id: 5, name: "Item 3.2"},
        {id: 6, name: "Item 3.3"}]}
]
```

Using angularJS 1.2 (I need to support IE8) i would like to create:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <optgroup label="Item 3">
        <option value="4">Item 3.1</option>
        <option value="5">Item 3.2</option>
        <option value="6">Item 3.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

So I need to loop over the top level items creating an option for each but for those with sub items I need to create an option group then loop over the subitems creating an option for each.

In any other language I would do a loop with an if statement to determine what element to use, however in angular you seem to have to create an element for a ng-repeat. In html you can't wrap each `<option>` with another element (`<div>` or `<span>`). So I'm stuck.

I need an element-less ng-repeat. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: I'm not understanding this completely.  I created a Plunker of your code.  Can you use it to explain what it is you want it to do? http://plnkr.co/edit/uyQBNabfVMQCXgKVpQmi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.item = [
    {id: 1, name: "Item 1", subItems: []},
    {id: 2, name: "Item 2", subItems: []},
    {id: 3, name: "Item 3", subItems: [[
        {id: 4, name: "Item 3.1"},
        {id: 5, name: "Item 3.2"},
        {id: 6, name: "Item 3.3"}]
            ]}
            ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item">{{item.name}}
              <span ng-if="item.subItems" ng-repeat="subItems in item.subItems">
                 <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="subItems in subItems">{{subItems.name}}</li>
                  </ul>
              </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is this you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is not possible (If I am understanding this correctly).  Take a look here [Option Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select): https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 and here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)