# How to use nested optgroup reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this nested `optgroup`:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="A">
<optgroup label="B">
     <option>C</option>
     <option>D</option>
     <option>G</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="J">
     <option>K</option>
     <option>L</option>
     <option>M</option>

</optgroup>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

but the result is:

[image]

Comment: what is the expected result? what have you tried? why is this related to react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` from `react-select`.

```js
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  {
    label: "A",
    options: [
      {
        label: "B",
        options: [
          {
            label: "C",
            value: 1
          },
          {
            label: "D",
            value: 2
          },
          {
            label: "G",
            value: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "J",
        options: [
          {
            label: "K",
            value: 4
          },
          {
            label: "L",
            value: 5
          },
          {
            label: "M",
            value: 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const NestedOptGroup = () => <Select name="options" options={options} />
```

There is a working example of this react-select feature: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-8xxyx?file=/index.js

**Source:** [How can I create nested option groups in React Select (V2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63048771/8248811)

Answer (score 0):

you can use only 1 sub group, like this

```
  <select>
    <optgroup label="B">
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>G</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="J">
      <option>K</option>
      <option>L</option>
      <option>M</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

if you wish add more subgroups you need to hack the identation
here have other answers for this:
[Nesting optgroups in a dropdownlist/select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037732/nesting-optgroups-in-a-dropdownlist-select)